# Android select always layout-normal folder

Tags: java, android, xml, user-interface

When I am trying to run my app on emulators, ALWAYS the layout-normal folder is selected. I tries to rum my app on 3.2 inch device and in 5 inch device, and in both of them android chooses to use layout-normal folder. Someone have an idea why it is like this?

I have also layout-small.. and also layout-large, but is always choose the same.

This is the look of me res/ folder.

[image]

Comment: What is the dp of devices?

Comment: How can I know it? The 5 inch device is Nexsus 5 (Resolution: 1080 * 1920 - xxhdpi), and the 3.2 device (is 320*480 - mdpi).

Comment: try to add screenshot of your res folder tree

Comment: I solve it! My problem was that I called the directories: layout-small, layout-large and etc. I solve it by change it to layout-hdpi, layout-xhdpi and etc. Is this is how should I do it?

Comment: No! those modifier is for Drawable folder. you should use sw-xxxdp modifier. You must read this article:  http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: But how do I know what to put in xxx? I understand that it sould be dp, but how do I know what dp belongs to each size? Thanks for taking time and answering. And btw it works, so why it's not good?

Comment: The answer is long. Read the article, it very fundemental

Comment: Ok, so I read it, I updated my question with my layout tree folder. it still pick the same directory for different screen sizes. I run my code on Galaxy S5 which have 400dp width, and it still somehow chooses to use the one with 300dp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I think I may see your problem. You have activity_main xml file in the default layout res folder, and probably you inflate this and not main_activity that you define to different sizes.